# Are changes in flexibility from stretching due to changes in the nerves or the muscles?

Tags: muscles

For many people, stretching repeatedly over a period of time improves their flexibility. I want to know whether this improvement commonly seen is due to a change in the nerves or the muscle’s material properties.

Are the changes in flexibility seen on the order of minutes/hours to weeks/months due to changes in the nervous system's reaction (e.g. reflex habituation) or changes in the viscoelasticy properties of the muscles (e.g. muscle length via serial sarcomere number)?

---

## Excerpts:

To help answerers, I want to provide a few excerpts from two sources. The first source is from 1998.

> "This article reviews recent findings regarding passive properties of
> the hamstring muscle group during stretch based on a model that was
> developed which could synchronously and continuously measure passive
> hamstring resistance and electromyographic activity, while the
> velocity and angle of a stretch was controlled. Resistance to stretch
> was defined as passive torque (Nm) offered by the hamstring muscle
> group during passive knee extension using an isokinetic dynamometer
> with a modified thigh pad. To simulate a clinical static stretch, the
> knee was passively extended to a pre-determined final position (0.0875
> rad/s, dynamic phase) where it remained stationary for 90s (static
> phase)."
>
> “A significant decrease was observed for energy (30%) and
> stiffness (13%) in the dynamic phase, and passive torque in the static
> phase. However, the observed decline in the variables measured was
> transient and they returned to baseline within 1h.”
>
> “Long-term stretching (3 weeks) increased joint range of motion as a result of a
> change in stretch tolerance rather than in passive properties.”

Source: Magnusson, Stig Peter. "Passive properties of human skeletal muscle during stretch maneuvers." *Scandinavian journal of medicine & science in sports* 8.2 (1998): 65-77.

The second source I want to cite is *The Complete Guide to Stretching* by Christopher Norris. Paraphrasing pages 56-58, he says stretching can affect the following:

- Habituation – when the stretch reflex becomes desensitized and the
  reflex doesn’t activate as easily when stretched
- Muscle stiffness – a muscle has an elastic recoil when stretched. The degree of this
  recoil is the “muscle stiffness”
- Stretch tolerance – the amount of discomfort induced by a stretch that a person can endure
- Serial Sarcomere Number (SSN) – a muscle can lengthen or shorten in length
  when the number of sarcomeres change

Norris also notes that the first 3 criteria usually change on the order of months (called “acute” or short-term) while the SSN tends to change on the order of years (called “chronic” or long-term).